# Allow special characters like (Turkish characters)

Tags: android, character-encoding, android-edittext, special-characters, utf

I want to give `permission` my android app. on EditText allow turkish characters as ('ş','ğ','İ',ı).I try to add them in my `layout`:

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textFilter"
android:digits="@string/myAlphaNumeric" />
```

And `string.xml`;

```
<string name="myAlphaNumeric">abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrsştuüvwxyzABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTUÜVWXYZ0123456789</string>
```

But did not work!!

Also;
`edtText.setText("şçüığŞÇÜİĞ")` is work.I can see on app screen.
But I just enter that characters on screen nothing show.

Comment: Try to use inputType as ""text". See my answer.

Comment: Make sure your layout includes the complete XML heading, with the UTF-8 encoding (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`).

Comment: I'm sure Xml heading @Noise Generator. Actually my EditText allow to some turkish characters like 'ç' ,'ü' ,'ö' but does not allow 'ş','ğ','İ',ı thats.

Comment: Then the font you're using does not provide all the required glyphs. Imagine fonts like a serie of SVGs. If the font maker doesn't draw all the characters, the font is incomplete. Try changing to a specific font.

Comment: I can not change font and should not add all special characters one by one

Comment: I try to add textView all turkish characters as('ş','ğ','İ',ı,ç,ü,ö)   i can see when i run app so changing Font is irrelevant this situation @Noise Generator

Comment: So, what is relevant, in your opinion? I just tried to give you a possible idea to solve your problem.

Comment: I know  you want to help me and thanx for it but i just think this problem should be on emulator or something because of emulator's does not sense 'ğ','ş','ı' when try on my keybord.

Answer (score -1):

Just use inputType as "text" instead of "textFilter":

```
<EditText
android:inputType="text"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with this? If you make inputType as text, you can enter special characters of keyboard.